# Is https://www.x.com/developers/paypal still existing

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I'm implementing a fundraising plugin in my Wordpress crowd funding website. And the guide says  I need to sign-up in the https://www.x.com/developers/paypal site so that PayPal knows mine's not a scam site and legitimately processing delayed payments (advanced crowd funding).

However the site seems to be not existing, any help? Thanks

Here's the link of the Fundraising plugin I'm using: https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/fundraising/?rtruste=1&https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/fundraising/?rtruste=1&utm_expid=3606929-46.O3zA8dlfQ7OjzdOy6sld8g.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

Comment: Implementing Paypal is a real pain for me, some of their links seems down most of the time.

Comment: Which is the plugin name?

Answer (score 0):

x.com has transitioned over to https://developer.paypal.com/